# Problem passing parameters with Android WebService Client and PHP server

Tags: php, android, web-services

I have the following code which calls a PHP webservice. The code connects to the service, but the paramters are not passed well. The method is just returning the parameters and for the following code it returns "mm" (basicly it returns the first letter of the first parameter twice).

```
    String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:server#userAuth"; 
    String METHOD_NAME = "userAuth";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo p1 = new PropertyInfo();
    p1.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    p1.setName("usr");
    p1.setValue("myuser");
    p1.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
    request.addProperty(p1);

    PropertyInfo p2 = new PropertyInfo();
    p2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    p2.setName("pass");
    p2.setValue("xxxxxxxxxxx");
    p2.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
    request.addProperty(p2);      

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
    return result.toString();
```

And here is the php server code...

```
$server = new nusoap_server;
$server->configureWSDL('server', 'urn:server');
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:server';
$server->register('userAuth',
            array('usr' => 'xsd:string', 'pass' => 'xsd:string'),
            array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
            'urn:server',
            'urn:server#userAuth');

function userAuth($value){

    $a=$value['usr'].$value['pass'];

        return $a;    
}

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';

$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally made it work by adding parameters in another instance of a SoapObject witch will pe called by the SoapObject of the request .The final code is:

String SOAP_ACTION = "userAuth"; 
        String METHOD_NAME = "userAuth";

```
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapObject parameters = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    parameters.addProperty("usr",  "myuser");
    parameters.addProperty("pass", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    Request.addProperty(METHOD_NAME, parameters); 



    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);


    Object result = (Object)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
    return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

request.addProperty("name1", values1);
request.addProperty("name2", values2);



SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
Object result = (Object)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
final String str =  result.toString();
```